# Is fact table normalised or denormalised or partially normalised?

Tags: data-warehouse

How would you categorise fact table in Data warehouse ? Is fact table normalised or denormalised or partially normalised.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703985/fact-table-is-in-normalized-or-de-normalized-form/22746286#22746286

Answer (score 0):

I will quote wikipedia:

> Fact tables are often defined by their grain. The grain of a fact table represents the most atomic level by which the facts may be defined.

Fact table (a measure holder table in star/snowflake  schema) is **denormalised**.